# App renders, an error occurs without interaction.Making changes halts rendering, showing 'CANNOT GET /login.'App still runs, indicating routing issue

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-dom

[Error shown in the Browser Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ2Xq.png)

When the app renders in the browser the error occurs by default without any interaction.When i make any changes in my react app , the rendering stops suddendly and shows "CANNOT GET /login" .But the app is still running on the specified port.It shows the issue is with routing .What to do to reslove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by passing a Boolean value to an attribute that expects a string. In your example, the attribute `inline` expects a string value, not a Boolean value.

You should pass a string value to it, like `inline="true"`.

Here's the corrected code:

```html
<button inline="true">Click me</button>
```

Instead of:

```html
<button inline=true>Click me</button>
```

By using `inline="true"`, you are providing the expected string value, and the issue should be resolved.

*If you're still confused, please let me know and I'll be happy to help clarify further.*